# Android layout coding on Java: declaration location

Tags: android, android-layout

I was trying out coding android layout on Java. Then, I noticed that following code is incorrect (as in not working):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout topLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    Button button1 = new Button(this);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ... setText, layoutParam and etc ...
        topLayout.addView(button1, layoutParam);
        setContentView(topLayout);
    }
}
```

while following code is correct (working):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout topLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        ... setText, layoutParm and etc ...
        topLayout.addView(button1, layoutParam);
        setContentView(topLayout);
    }
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: probably because the context (`this` i.e. your `Activity`) is not initialised correctly yet. Whereas in the latter you call it in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

The `context` of an `Activity` is created once `onCreate()` is called.
 In the first case, you don't have context set.

Answer (score 0):

The comment made by @Blundell explains it, but if you want to go a little bit deeper, you need to understand the object lifecycle and order of things.

An Activity is a Java Object in the end. And so it must go through the Java Object creation process.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    LinearLayout topLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    Button button1 = new Button(this);
```

Member variables (or Fields) are created right after the constructor. If you don't have a constructor, one is created for you (even tho you don't see it) you can try to create one:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public MainActivity() {
       super();
       Log.d("MAINACTIVITY", "Constructor!");
    }
```

Now add log to your onCreate()…

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("MAINACTIVITY", "onCreate!");
}
```

Start your Activity and look at the log.

You should see:

```
Constructor!
onCreate!
```

With that being said, Since an Activity implements a Context interface, you cannot use them  until they are not constructed, something that can be considered done  **after** the constructor is called and ends.

Field members which are initialized inline, must be initialized during object Construction too, because that's the idea of their initialization being there…

So in short, you're trying to initialize **Field Members** that require something (a context) that is not yet available because it hasn't been created (*this*).

;)